# Robot framework: Using faker to generate a prefix string for account data

Tags: python, robotframework, test-data, faker

I'm writing test cases that test the functionality of adding an account. This means that I need to generate data for the Account's: Name, email, reference no and order no. I was thinking that for each of these fields I could just generate a random word or number with a prefix so that I can use a script to delete these entries from the database regularly.

The issue is, I'm not sure how to add prefixes or indeed just *use* most of faker's keywords.

At the minute I'm using the md5 keyword to create a string that I can use for each instance of my test case, I've done so by creating a variable in my resource file:

```
*** Variables ***
${md5}                MD 5
```

I then call this variable whenever I wish to write my prefix (I call it at the end of various fields eg. email: email+${md5}@gmail.com, reference: test ${md5} etc

```
*** Keywords ***
Write username
    Input Text    a11y-username    test ${md5}
```

I'm not sure where the actual documentation is for using faker from within Robot Framework, I'm using http://fake-factory.readthedocs.org/en to find the providers I want to use and then struggle to get them working from within RF.

Can anyone either help me get random_int() working, or point me to the relevant documentation for *ALL* faker providers in RF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

Using faker keywords requires nothing more than to call them, and save the results in a variable. You *cannot* use faker keywords in the variable table, you need to use them within a testcase or keyword. However, you can directly call the faker commands from with a python variable file.

To get an address, for example, you would call the `Address` keyword. Because the faker keywords are so generic, I recommend fully qualifying the keywords to make it clear you're generating fake data.

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | FakerLibrary | WITH NAME | faker

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of using faker
| | ${address}= | faker.Address
| | log | address: ${address}
```

### Using the Random Int keyword

To get a random integer, use the Random Integer keyword:

```
| Example of using faker to get a random integer
| | ${number}= | faker.Random Int
| | log | my number is ${number}
```

### Initializing variables for the whole suite

If you want to use the same values for an entire suite, you can write a keyword that sets some suite-level variables using the [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) keyword.

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | FakerLibrary | WITH NAME | faker
| Suite Setup | Initialize Test Data

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of using faker to initialize suite variables
| | log | The suite address is ${address}
| | log | The suite md5 is ${md5}
| | log | The suite number is ${number}


*** Keywords ***
| Initialize test data
| | ${address}= | faker.Address
| | ${md5}= | faker.MD5
| | ${number}= | faker.Random Int
| | 
| | Set suite variable | ${address}
| | Set suite variable | ${md5}
| | Set suite variable | ${number}
```

### Documentation

FakerLibrary keyword documentation is available at https://guykisel.github.io/robotframework-faker/.

Comment: But as you can see in my code example, I've created a variable that calls a faker keyword and stored it in a variable, because I can call that variable and get the same output.

Why can't I do this with random_int or another faker provider?

Comment: There is no such thing as "call that variable". Variables can't be called. In the variable table, the second column is a string, not a keyword. Your variable is nothing but a string containing the characters "MD 5". Your `${md5}` variable doesn't call anything and doesn't use faker. It's just a normal variable. Again, to use faker you must call one of the faker keywords such as `Random Int`.

Comment: After looking at the documentation you linked, MD 5 (the value of the variable when defined) is a keyword, which is why the variable `${md5}` has a value generated by faker, as I said.

I'm now testing to see if I can do the same with Random Int

Comment: @Stormie: No offense, but I think you are mistaken. Look at your test logs, you'll see that `${md5}` isn't an md5, it's just the string "MD 5". It cannot be anything else unless you're using some other tool besides robotframework. If you put something in the variables table, that second column is just a literal string, nothing more.

Comment: Ah, I apologise. When I had been testing this earlier (trying to call the keyword in the variable definition) I hadn't un-commented the relevant code.

You're quite correct, I take it that I will still have to set the variable to keep the random int generated in this session?

Comment: Yes, you have to set a variable to the result of the keyword, in order to use the result of the keyword in your test.