# Robot framework: Storing faker-generated data for the duration of the test suite

Tags: storage, robotframework, faker

I have created a *suffix* for any test data I use in my test cases, for instance when adding an account you must enter a name for it, I use the static text "test" and then add the *suffix* to the end of this, this is what I do for all fields.

However, I need to check that this data has been saved correctly and is displayed correctly during these test cases so I need to somehow make Robot Framework remember this suffix I've generated. So far in my test cases I've just been using `set variable` after generating the data with faker, but obviously this is contained within the keyword, how could I make it so that this generated data is accessible for the duration of my testing session (until all tests, in the folder are finished)?

My code at the minute:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page
    ${num}=    Random Int
    ${suffix}=    set variable    ${num}

    Input Text    username    ${suffix}
```

To reiterate, I then want to check this *${suffix}* value in another test case

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Test suite file

```
*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Fill field    a11y-username    ${MYNUM}
```

Resource file

```
*** Variables ***
${MYNUM}      

*** Keywords ***
Suite Setup
    ${MYNUM}=    Random Int
    Set Suite Variable  ${MYNUM}
```

Comment: Though not a duplicate, this answer addresses that question by showing how to use set suite variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24869700/7432

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised you had edited your answer. After looking over it, it was very very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the ["set suite variable"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) keyword for that. I would create a Suite Setup (in a **init**.txt file if you have several files in your folders for your different tests) that creates this ${suffix} and make it available for all tests in the suite:

```
${num}=  Random Int
${SUFFIX}=  set suite variable  ${num}
```

note: I use capital letters to show that the variable has a bigger scope than just local